Sending Auditd Logs to Central Server Uubntu 22.04
I want to setup logging using auditd on multiple clients and send their logs to a central logging server (using audispd-plugins package).
I was following a couple of guides:
https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2016/08/06/setting-up-centralized-logging-with-auditd/
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/linux-auditing-system-centralized-logging-to-remote-server-9644089702fb
But I don't see the logs for the client in /var/log/audit/audit.log on the central server.
Here are my steps
Logging Server
sudo apt install -y auditd

Edit the logging config file to allow listen to port 60.
sudo vim /etc/audit/auditd.conf

Add the following line.
tcp_listen_port = 60

Edit /etc/audit/auditd.conf to have the following line:
name_format = hostname

Restart the daemon.
sudo service auditd restart

Logging Clients
Install auditd and audispd
sudo apt install -y audispd-plugins

Alter /etc/audit/rules.d
Use the following template and update /etc/audit/rules.d: https://github.com/Neo23x0/auditd/blob/master/audit.rules
sudo su
cd /etc/audit/rules.d
rm audit.rules
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Neo23x0/auditd/master/audit.rules

Alter settings to send logs to Logging Server
vim /etc/audit/audisp-remote.conf

Add the following to the top of the conf file.
remote_server = <ip of logging server>
port = 60

Edit /etc/audit/auditd.conf to have the following line:
name_format = hostname

Activate remote logging plugins
Open the following file.
vim /etc/audit/plugins.d/au-remote.conf

Edit the file to match the following.
active = yes

Finally, restart the service.
service auditd restart


Have you checked for errors in the journal? ```
journalctl -xef -u auditd.service


Thanks for the comment! I was actually just looking in the logs recently and have found this error.
Jun 06 15:37:28 auditd-client audisp-remote[566]: startup network failure, First attempt at connecting to server unsuccessful
I do have the firewall open for tcp/60 as well.

I had given up on this for a few months and tried again recently. Apparently the "listener" is disabled by default when you install the package on Ubuntu.
See the following reference: https://xn--blgg-hra.no/2016/01/auditd-in-ubuntu-not-listening/
Instead I used Debian as the central logging server and it works.
